# Spring MVC 3 User Defined Exception handling with User defined View

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-mvc, exception

How to handle user defined exceptions (Custom Exception ex.: "BusinessException") in Spring MVC 3 with custom message and view name ?

For Example :

If i throw my own exception from Service layer it should be caught and should redirect to specified view with message, the view name may be same or different.

I searched in Google, but no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**----SOLVED----**

Thanks for all who have helped me to achieve solution for my problem.
Finally i got solution for this.

The answer is "ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver" class from Spring 3.1, By overriding "resolveException" method.

Thank You all.

Answer (score 6):

Have you checked `@ExceptionHandler`

for eg :

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyBusinessException.class)
public ModelAndView handleMyBusinessException(MyBusinessException e) {
   handle it or log it or redirect to error page after populating a model
}
```

This has advantage of having Exception handled at Spring MVC level itself , you can populate a model and bring up a meaningful error page.

Otherwise you can configure it in web.xml as other answer suggests. But your error page will be more  like a static page.

Comment: Hi Subin, Thanks for your post. Yes, here we can populate our own model with message and view. But again view name will be tightly coupled. Can you please give an example ? i am not really convinced. Thank you.

Comment: just return new ModelAndView("errorviewname") from this method, before that populate dynamic content in ModelMap. It is same like other controller method.View name will be tightly coupled, why would you want to avoid it.Let me know the functionality that you are looking for.,

Comment: Ok. I have Controller class which will map 4 requests (4 methods). and from all method "MyBusinessException" is expected. And for all the method the view name will be different if exception is thrown. So if i have one exception handler method in my controller then how can i decide view name ?

Comment: easy solution is to set the view name in MyBusinessException object before it is thrown, so in error handler you know the view to forward request to

Comment: I can not set view name in "MyBusinessException" object. because it is thrown from Service Layer. and "MyBusinessException" is generic exception for whole service layer.

Comment: then your option is to have a try catch block in all four controllers. and catch mybusinessException , within catch block set view name to exception and throw again.

Comment: Subin, right now i am doing the same thing. but still we should not catch Service Layer Exceptions inside Controller. In struts 2 i done this by implementing my own exception mapping interceptor by extending "ExceptionMappingInterceptor" and by overriding "intercept" method which will return common result. and we will be assigning view name to this result in "struts.xml" inside <action> tag. So is there any thing like this in Spring MVC ? So  we can implement or extend exception mapping interceptor ? Thank you for your all posts.

Comment: we dont have any mapping for your four urls to their corresponding views out side controller methods. Only option is to handle it in Controller method so. Let see if some one can give a better oulook.

Comment: Subin, I just gave you the example about my controller which "may have 4 methods", i will be having hundreds of controllers in feature for my application and i don't want to write a exception handler method in every controller, this should not be the case. And this is not the only option i think. Any way i am also trying. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Subin, After some research i think i have found some solution. The Class provided by Spring is "SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" and abstract class "HandlerInterceptorAdapter". Do you know how to implement ? and which one i have to use. I tried a lot but not successful. I am new to "Spring MVC".

Answer (score 2):

You have to propagate exception from service layer to controller layer there you can usedeclarative exception handling and provide exception to view mapping in spring configuration xml

Comment: Hi, Thanks you for your post. After some research i think i have found some solution. The Class provided by Spring is "SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" and abstract class "HandlerInterceptorAdapter". Do you know how to implement ? and which one i have to use. I tried a lot but not successful. I am new to "Spring MVC".